# Getting the right Id widget at startup

Tags: java, android, widget

I use the following code :

My main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int idWidget;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
        idWidget=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("com.example.testwidget.myIntent.IDWidget");

        Toast.makeText(this,"Id widget : "+Integer.toString(idWidget),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

My widget provider :

```
public class myWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context contexte, AppWidgetManager gestionnaireWidget, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    int appWidgetId;
    RemoteViews vue;
    Intent intentPostIt;
    PendingIntent pendingIntentPostIt;

    Toast.makeText(contexte,"Starting updating widgets",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Toast.makeText(contexte,"Id widget : "+Integer.toString(appWidgetId),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        intentPostIt = new Intent(contexte,MainActivity.class);

        Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO,"Intent : "+intentPostIt.toString());

        intentPostIt.setAction("com.example.testwidget.myIntent");
        intentPostIt.putExtra("com.example.testwidget.myIntent.IDWidget",appWidgetId);
        pendingIntentPostIt = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexte,0, intentPostIt,0);

        Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO,"Intent extra : "+Integer.toString(intentPostIt.getIntExtra("GL.PostIt.IDWidget",-1)));

        vue=new RemoteViews(contexte.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_description);
        vue.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget,pendingIntentPostIt);
        gestionnaireWidget.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,vue);
    }

    Toast.makeText(contexte,"Ending updating widgets",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

With this code, when a first widget is added on the home screen, a `Toast` informs you that the AppWidgetManager's `update` function is starting. A second `Toast` gives you the Id of the widget being processed. A third one informs you of the end of the `update` function.

If you add a second widget on the home screen, the same sequence will repeat, but with another Id number.

Now, click on the first widget : the main activity is launched and a `Toast` gives you the Id bound with the `Intent` that started the application. Close the app and touch the other widget : tha app is launched again and another `Toast` appear. In my opinion, it should give the Id of the second widget. That's not the case : the first Id is displayed again.

Why doesn't my application retrieve the good Id numbers when launched by the second widget? Is there anything wrong with my code? Is it how is it supposed to work? If yes, how could I distinguish which widget launched the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use flags with your PendingIntent like this:

```
    pendingIntentPostIt = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexte,0, intentPostIt,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Without that flag the extra data you put arent updated since the same PendingIntent already exists in the system and the system just returns the first one you created without updating its data.

Read this carefully to fully understand why is this happening: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

From the doc:

*A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.
Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.*

.....

Comment: The use of the "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" is not a solution : instead of having twice the first widget Id, I get twice the second! I can't neither distinguish which widget was at the origin of the launch of the application. But talking about the "PendingIntent" was a good lead : by passing the widget Id in the request code, I have been able to get the widget Id of the trigerring widget. My problem is then solved.